# The converse of a theorem about Krull rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

[Proposition 4.2](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/ln/tifr30.pdf) of P. Samuel's "Lectures on UFD's" says that the localization of a Krull ring $A$ with respect to a multiplicatively closed set $S$, $S^{-1}A$, is again a Krull ring.

**My question:** When the converse of the above proposition is true?

- Generally there exists a counterexample; just take any integral domain $A$ which is not a Krull ring and $S=A-\{0\}$. Then $S^{-1}A$ is the field of fractions of $A$, which is trivially a Krull ring, but $A$ is not a Krull ring (by assumption).
- Therefore: What additional conditions on the
  multiplicatively closed set $S$ and/or on $A$ one must impose in order to get the converse?
  For example, is it true that assuming that $S$ is "primal" will imply that
  $A$ is Krull (given $S^{-1}A$ is Krull, of course)? See [Page 251; Theorem 15.39](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf) (Nagata's theorem).
  What about $S$ generated by one element? (not necessarily a prime element).